# Nav items not aligned in the same line after applying border-bottom to the active item in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, navbar

I need help on aligning the nav items in the same line after applying border to the active item

[image]

My [StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9ttch)

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question. Posting it on a third party site that may go away, be blocked, or just disappear makes your question lose all value to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add `border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;` to `li`. This is because of the box-model. Since The active element has the border defined, it's box will be bigger than the inactive elements.

```
.navbar {
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want
[image]

```css
.navbar {
    height: 100px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: lightpink;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

or
[image]

```css
.navbar {
    height: 100px;
}

ul {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightpink;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

li.active::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **some** possibilities:

- Add `padding-top: 5px` to the active items.
- Put all the `<li>` elements with the same `border-bottom` but changing the `border-color` or transparency in the active class.
- Use pseudo elements to simulate the `border-bottom`. See the following code here or check this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/aruizh/pen/dyPOOBK)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li.active::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="active">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```